# Ошибка конвертации pdf в png

Tags: python, ubuntu

Пытаюсь сконвертировать PPTX в PDF на Ubuntu 18.04:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf 7.pptx
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
func=xmlSecCheckVersionExt:file=xmlsec.c:line=188:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=19:invalid version:mode=abi compatible;expected minor version=2;real minor version=2;expected subminor version=25;real subminor version=26
convert /home/..../presentation7/7.pptx -> /home/..../presentation7/7.pdf using filter : impress_pdf_Export
```

Причем не просто ошибку -  а прям встает. В итоге потом отменяешь и он создает битый PDF-файл.

---

UPD:

Нашел способ ка сконвертировать:

```
unoconv -v -f pdf file.pptx
```

Проверил через консоль - конвертирует, но если интегрировать в python-скрипт, то в одном месте отрабатывает, а в другом нет (хотя виртуальное пространство одно и то же - это 1 приложение на VDS).

Решил принтануть результат, чтобы посмотреть что там:

```
path_ppt_file = '/home/...../3.pptx'
cmd = f'unoconv -v -f pdf {path_ppt_file}'
rezult = subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                  shell=True, encoding='utf-8')
print(rezult )
```

В итоге такой результат:

> CompletedProcess(args=['unoconv', '-v', '-f', 'pdf', '/home/...../3.pptx'], returncode=127, stdout='-v: 1: -v: unoconv: not found\n')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Оставлю обработчик, если кому понадобится. Если есть есть возможность оптимизации кода, то я только за.

```
import datetime
import os

def made_folder(verify_path):
    if os.path.exists(verify_path):
        pass
    else:
        os.mkdir(verify_path)
    return verify_path

class Convert_file():
    def __init__(self, name_file, ubuntu_pref, path_to_folder, exception='pdf'):
        # === У всех путей не указывать в конце слеш! ===
        # name_file = имя файла без расширения
        # exception - расширение файла
        # ubuntu_pref - путь Ubuntu до проекта
        # path_to_folder - расположение относительно проекта

        self.name_file = name_file
        self.exception = exception
        self.ubuntu_pref = ubuntu_pref
        self.path_to_folder = path_to_folder

        self.process_convert = []

        self.is_convert_pptx_in_pdf = False
        self.is_convert_pdf_in_png = False

        self.url_first_slide = f'{self.path_to_folder}/covers/slide-01.png'

        self.cover_presentation = 'static/wait.gif'

    def convert_pptx_to_pdf(self, exception_file='pptx'):
        # === КОНВЕРТАЦИЯ pptx  В pdf ===
        path_ppt_file = f'{self.path_to_folder}/{self.name_file}.{exception_file}'

        # -- Проверка есть ли PPTX-файл ---
        if self.is_file(path_ppt_file):
            # -- Проверка есть ли PDF-файл ---
            path_pdf = f'{self.path_to_folder}/{self.name_file}.pdf'
            if self.is_file(path_pdf):
                self.add_proc_conv(proc='conv ppt',
                                   rezult=False,
                                   cmd='pdf-file created')
            else:
                cmd = f'/usr/bin/soffice soffice --headless "-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_{self.name_file}" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir {self.path_to_folder} {self.ubuntu_pref}/{path_ppt_file}'

                child = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding='utf-8', shell=False)

                self.wait_process(child)

                if child.returncode == 0:
                    self.add_proc_conv(proc='conv ppt',
                                       rezult=True,
                                       cmd=cmd,
                                       dop=(child, child.returncode))
                    self.is_convert_pptx_in_pdf = True
                else:
                    self.add_proc_conv(proc='conv ppt',
                                       rezult=False,
                                       cmd=cmd)
        else:
            self.add_proc_conv(proc='conv ppt',
                           rezult=False,
                           cmd='no ppt-file',
                           dop=path_ppt_file)

    def convert_pdf_to_png(self):
        work_dir = f'{self.ubuntu_pref}/{self.path_to_folder}'

        path_pdf_file = f'{self.path_to_folder}/{self.name_file}.pdf'
        # --- ПРОВЕРКА есть ли PDF-файл ---
        if self.is_file(path_pdf_file):
            if self.is_file(self.url_first_slide):
                self.add_proc_conv(proc='conv pdf',
                                   rezult=False,
                                   cmd='first png-file created',
                                   dop=self.url_first_slide)
                self.cover_presentation = self.url_first_slide
            else:
                convert_dir_png = made_folder(verify_path=f'{work_dir}/covers')
                cmd = f'gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -o {convert_dir_png}/slide-%02d.png -r96 {work_dir}/{self.name_file}.pdf'

                child = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding='utf-8',
                                     shell=False)
                self.wait_process(child)
                if (child.returncode == 0) and (self.is_file(self.url_first_slide)):
                    self.add_proc_conv(proc='conv pdf',
                                       rezult=True,
                                       cmd=cmd,
                                       dop=child)
                    self.is_convert_pdf_in_png = True
                    self.cover_presentation = self.url_first_slide

                else:
                    self.add_proc_conv(proc='conv pdf',
                                       rezult=False,
                                       cmd=cmd)
        else:
            self.add_proc_conv(proc='conv pdf',
                               rezult=False,
                               cmd='no pdf-file')
    def add_proc_conv(self, proc, rezult, cmd, dop=None):
        self.process_convert.append(
            {proc: rezult,
             'cmd': cmd,
             'dop': dop
             }
        )

    def is_file(self, path_to_file_full):
        # == Проверяет есть ли файл ==
        return os.path.exists(path_to_file_full)

    def wait_process(self, child):
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        while True:
            curent_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            if child.returncode == 0:
                break
            delta = curent_time - start_time
            if delta.total_seconds() > 15:
                break
            if child.poll() == 0:
                break
```